# while loop and interpreting values as True or False

Tags: python

The following program is from a book of python. In this code, count is first set to 0 and then `while True` is used. In the book I read that zeros and empty strings are evaluated as False while all the other values are evaluated as True. If that is the case then how the program executes the while loop? wouldn't the count evaluated as False as the count is set to 0?

Could someone please explain this?

```
# Finicky Counter
# Demonstrates the break and continue statements

count = 0  
while True:         # while count is True
    count += 1

    # end loop if count greater than 10
    if count > 10:
       break
    # skip 5
    if count == 5:
        continue
    print(count)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: `# while count is True` this comment is confusing. In that particular line, code only checks value of `True` and since it's true, it goes in to `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in code portion `while True`, the condition will always evaluate to true. Now lets go inside the while loop.

when `count > 10` is evaluated, for count = 0, it is false, so while count < 10, it will not break out of while loop.

If it was `while count:` Yes it would have come out of the loop in the first iteration itself as `while count:` is equivalent to - `while count != 0`

for condition `count == 5` it continues on to next iteration, and does not print inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you evaluate

```
if count: # and count is zero
       break
```

then sure - the loop will break immediately.
But you are evaluating this expression:

```
if count > 10: # 0 > 10
```

which is `False`, so you won't break on the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed `while True:` to `while count:`, your assumption would indeed be correct

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say `while count:`  You said `while True:`  Since `True` is always `True`, your loop will run forever unless something inside tells it not to.  That could be a line that says `break`, or it could be an exception raised.  Your loop will break if `count` is greater than `10`.  `count` starts out at zero, but at the first iteration, `count += 1` happens and `count` is now one.  Since `count` is not greater than ten, it does not break.  Since `count` is not equal to `5`, it doesn't continue either.  All it does is print `1`.  At the next iteration, `count` increments again and the same thing happens with the `if` statements.  It is the same until eventually, the iteration where `count` is equal to `4` ends.  Since `True` is still `True`, the iteration happens again.  `count` is incremented and now equals five.  The `if count > 10:` statement is `False`, but `if count == 5:` is `True`, so the loop just skips the `print` call and goes back to the beginning of the loop.  The first thing it gets to is `count += 1`, so `count` is now equal to six.  The next few iterations are quite similar to what happened before `count` was five.  Once the iteration where `count` is nine happens, it gets to the beginning of the loop and increments `count`.  Now `count` is ten and the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is a loop that will run a portion of code until the condition is False.
**while True** is called infinite loop because True is not a condition and therefore can not change. So the loop will run until it found the break instruction.

Here you have two special elements related to loops :

- continue : go directly to next iteration
- break : go out of the loop